# Sinch Client works but messages aren't being sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, sinch

I'm using sinch and I've gotten the client to work by registering a user, but I can't send a message. When I click my send button, nothing happens. The required methods that need to be implemented, such as messageFailed(), messageDelivered(), etc. are not being called either. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you registered the one more user? Can you enable logging and share the full log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you registered the one more user? Can you enable logging and share the full log output.

See comment below, user tried to send message to self

Comment: I haven't no, but shouldn't it error since the user does not exist and call the messageFailed() method?

Comment: I'm trying to register another user by logging him in through my app. The Sinch client gets called because of this message `2015-03-24 22:04:53.718 See[3701:125804] client did start` which is in my app delegate file in a method where the Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey() is called. The problem is in my dashboard, I still have 1 unique users, not 2. I'm using the iOS simulator to test all of this.

Comment: I guess there's a delay when users get registered on the dashboard. Because now it updated the unique user count.

Comment: You are right, the messageFailed method should be called. It seems like the messageclient delegate is not working at all. Do you have a repo to share where we could look at the code?

Comment: I fixed it, it turns out the ID was the same ID as the person sending the message -.-